# Using DBconnection with ASP.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use ASP.Net core Identity.
In the .Net Framework, to construct IdentityDBContext I can pass DBConnection (see the link).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn468085(v=vs.108)

I want to use .Net core Identity. The issue is IdentityDBContext in .Net Core has not constructor with DBCOnnection. Is there a way (workaround) to contract IdentityDBcontext with DBConnection?

Comment: Have you read this [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-5.0)?

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net core, there are two ways connect to database.

First Way:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }
}
```

Register the service:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Second Way:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"));
```

Comment: I find a workaround for the issue.Thank you

Comment: So please share your answer to help others if they will meet the same issue.

Comment: I did something like this
            public ApplicationDbContext(DbConnection dbConnection)
            :base(new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlServer(dbConnection).Options)

However, if someone has a better answer it will be great.